# Java Swing Table questions

Tags: java, swing

Hey guys, working on an event calendar. I'm having some trouble getting my column heads to display.. here is the code

```
private JTable calendarTable;
private DefaultTableModel calendarTableModel; 

final private String [] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
                                    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",
                                    "Saturday"};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* Setup the actual calendar table */


calendarTableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
             return false;
    }
};

// setup columns
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    calendarTableModel.addColumn(days[i]); 

calendarTable = new JTable(calendarTableModel);

calendarTable.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
calendarTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

calendarTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
calendarTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
calendarTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

calendarTable.setRowHeight(105);
calendarTableModel.setColumnCount(7);
calendarTableModel.setRowCount(6);
```

Also, Im sort of new with tables.. how can I make the rowHeight split between the max size of the table?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by this: "how can I make the rowHeight split between the max size of the table?"

Comment: Well, I have 6 rows, I want them to fill the entire panel and each row be the same height.

Comment: add this 

JTableHeader header = new JTableHeader(); 

calendarTable.setTableHeader(header);

Comment: each row will be same height by default.. no need to set any row height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Table header**

Either put calendarTable in a JScrollPane, or add calendarTable.getTableHeader() as well.

**Row height**

Add a listener to change row height whenever the table is resized.

```
calendarTable.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getID() == ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_RESIZED) {
            calendarTable.setRowHeight(calendarTable.getHeight() / calendarTable.getRowCount());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Alright, well the row size is working great, but even with the JScrollPane and getTableHeader I can't get the headers to dis play!

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(calendarPanel);

Comment: working now! thanks! :) I simply needed to add the scrollPane to the panel rather than calendarTable